# What does "RemoteException" mean in general in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, terminology

1) May anyone help me about the concept of "Remoteexception"? What does it mean in general?

2) Also what does it mean by unwrapRemoteException? Was not sure it means by "if this remote exception wraps up one of the lookupTypes"

```
  /**
   * If this remote exception wraps up one of the lookupTypes
   * then return this exception.
   * <p>
   * Unwraps any IOException.
   * 
   * @param lookupTypes the desired exception class.
   * @return IOException, which is either the lookupClass exception or this.
   */
  public IOException unwrapRemoteException(Class<?>... lookupTypes) {
    if(lookupTypes == null)
      return this;
    for(Class<?> lookupClass : lookupTypes) {
      if(!lookupClass.getName().equals(getClassName()))
        continue;
      try {
        return instantiateException(lookupClass.asSubclass(IOException.class));
      } catch(Exception e) {
        // cannot instantiate lookupClass, just return this
        return this;
      }
    }
    // wrapped up exception is not in lookupTypes, just return this
    return this;
  }
```

(Hadoop_HDFS_Open_Source: https://github.com/apache/hadoop)

Thanks in advance! Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) May anyone help me about the concept of "Remoteexception"? What does it mean in general?

Remote Exception is thrown(created) in the server side. Server throws such exception because client sent invalid request, or server has internal error or something else. The RPC server in the server side serialized the exception, and sent it to client side. Client side deserializes the exception, and gets the exception.

> 2) Also what does it mean by unwrapRemoteException?

The question is "why we need to wrap exception". First, RemoteException is a wrapper not the real exception. The real exception thrown by server could be AccessControlException(the user has no previleage), FileNotFoundException(invalid request). We wrap them up inside a RemoteException. But why? Because the code is cleaner and more readable.

> Was not sure it means by "if this remote exception wraps up one of the lookupTypes"

For example, in DFSClient.java

```
public HdfsFileStatus getFileInfo(String src) throws IOException {
  checkOpen();
  try {
    return namenode.getFileInfo(src);
  } catch(RemoteException re) {
    throw re.unwrapRemoteException(AccessControlException.class,
                                   FileNotFoundException.class,
                                   UnresolvedPathException.class);
  }
}
```

If the `re` wraps a `FileNotFoundException`, then the `getFileInfo` only returns the `FileNotFoundException`. Then the user can see a shorter & cleaner exception message. The user only need to know the file is not found, don't care if it's remote or not.

But if the `re` wraps a `SafeModeException` or some unknown exception. It's probably some server's internal bug or configuration error. We throw the `re`(RemoteException) exactly. So the user can know the error is from remote(server side), even though the user doesn't know the wrapped `SafeModeException`(or some unknown exception). The user can ask help from tech support.